# Can anyone please explain me the output of this short C operations?

Tags: c, gdb, bit-manipulation, bit

please explain the sequence of BIT wise operation being performed in different cases.

```
(gdb) set $i = 1
(gdb) p $i << 1 + ($i << 3)
$11 = 512
(gdb) set $i = 1
(gdb) p ($i << 1) + $i << 3
$12 = 24
(gdb) set $i = 1
(gdb) p $i << 1 + $i << 3
$13 = 32
(gdb)
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: why it has to be homework problem, if it is too easy for you , kindly pls help me out to understand ?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand? Do you know what the left shift operator does? If not then you should be asking about that specifically. If so, what prevents you from working out the answer yourself? We can give you the answers but the answer may be better if you tell us what it is that you don't actually understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain one case and leave the rest to you.

```
(gdb) p $i << 1 + ($i << 3)
$11 = 512
```

On this line, reading from right to left, `$i` is initially 1 (0001 in binary), shift left `<<` 3 bits, we have `1000` because of the parentheses, then add 1 to get `1001`, which is 9. The next `<<` means shift `9` bits left from the initial `$i`, we have `2^9 = 512`. This is the result you see in the next line.

Notice how the original `$i` is not modified and you need to follow precedence.